# Simple Calling vector of a class I made "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, class, vector, push-back

***Quick intro*** I am having an issue when I define a simple class called 'token', that is comprised of two int values, and I make a vector out of this class. I am unable to use the 'push_back'. the compiler tells me my 'does not name a type'

***Code example***
//example of my class definition

```
class token{
public:
int hi;
int hello;

token(int hi, int hello)
:hi(hi), hello(hello){}
};
```

//here is how i call and use the class

```
vector<token> tok;
tok.push_back(1,1);
```

***disclaimer***So first off, I am a complete noob. I have spent many many hours googling/reading/etc trying to find the answer. Most of the time I haven't been able to fully understand what I was reading, so since I believe my issue is probably very simple I was hoping someone would be able to help me out.

I am using namespace std, please don't tell me that this is bad practice. lol I am just learning how to code, and it makes my life a lot simpler. I am calling in the correct libraries. But I am using SFML.

***Please Help*** So can you please me. I am completely lost. please believe me that I have wasted a better part of a day reading and reading different forums.
Thanks :) please keep it simple

Comment: I have tried tok.push_back(); and several other variants

Answer (score 7, accepted):

push_back require a reference to token object

```
tok.push_back( token(1,1) );
```

where emplace_back construct in the vector directly

```
tok.emplace_back( 1, 1 );
```

I believe you want the `emplace_back` as it is more efficient.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me why emplace_back is more efficient?

Comment: @Krtko cause `token(1,1)` is a temporary object which is going to be copied into the vector and destruct itself afterward, in this case it is one extra copy you dont really need.

Comment: So emplace_back does require the construction of the temp object?

Comment: But I really really appreciate your help